# Dynamically change an ng-model-options property

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement to present a time input field using a timezone offset determined by the selection of a user-profile on the same form.

I am defining a `getTzOffset` fn on scope in a link function so that I can use it in ng-model-options like this:

`<input ng-model="myTimeObject" type="time" ... ng-model-options="{timezone: getTzOffset()}" ... >`

But that doesn't work. getTzOffset never gets called.

I'm using a datepicker with the input field, which requires a timezone. I don't need a modified date object or a string representation of it, I need the timezone-offset so the datepicker can know how to translate the date object properly into UTC time. I need that timezone to change when a different user is selected through the interface.

Is there any way to dynamically change an ng-model-options property?

Comment: Have you already tried setting a scope variable rather than a function? Any change there?

Comment: Yeah, tried that. Set a scope var with an offset string at the top of the link function. Doesn't work at all. Just defaults to the browser's setting. It has to be a hard-coded string in the template or it just doesn't take. ng-model-options appears to not be an true angular expression (contrary to the docs).

Comment: I've resigned to recompiling the targetted code and re-inserting into the dom. I've got this working, but it's not the simple solution I wanted.

Comment: Would you mind showing us what that looks like? Some of us are curious (me)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the angular date filter option : timezone.

[Sample Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2QBmbvXBcV0CPtx3HKh9?p=preview).

The idea is to use the third parameter to the date filter and make it changeable via a variable.

```
{{ inputTime | date: "HH:mm:ss": tzInput }}
```

You could also use $filter to generate values in code and store it, like:

```
$scope.inputTime = $filter('date')($scope.inputTime , "HH:mm:ss", $scope.tzInput);
```

Comment: My model is a datetime object, not a string. I added a little more html for clarity.

Comment: But it returns a string. I'm using a datepicker with the input field, which requires a timezone. I don't need a modified date object or a string representation of it, I need the timezone so the datepicker can know how to manipulate the date object. (clarifying my question)